# Exe нормально запускается на всех компьютерах кроме одного (даже не дает ее снять в диспетчере задач)

Tags: c#, .net, exe

Написал программу, она нормально запускается с разных компьютеров кроме одного. При попытке запуска exe-файла программа грузится но ничего не делает. Если пытаюсь ее завершить через диспетчер задач, то пишет что не удалось, недостаточно прав. В логах после запуска нахожу 2 ошибки:

> Событие 1000
>
> Имя сбойного приложения: ReadingRus.vshost.exe, версия: 14.0.23107.0,
>   метка времени: 0x559b788a Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия:
>   6.3.9600.18264, метка времени: 0x56e1b34d Код исключения: 0xe0434352 Смещение ошибки: 0x00015b68 Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x34c
>   Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d1bc0e64311ecd Путь сбойного
>   приложения: `D:\ReadingRus\bin\Debug\ReadingRus.vshost.exe` Путь
>   сбойного модуля: `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll` Идентификатор
>   отчета: a2a22502-2801-11e6-828f-c4d9878c9555 Полное имя сбойного
>   пакета:
>
> Событие 1026(.NET Runtime)
>
> Приложение: `ReadingRus.vshost.exe` Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
>   Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
>   Сведения об исключении: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` Стек:    в
>   `Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.EntryPoint.Main()` Подскажите,
>   с чем связано?

Comment: `vshost.exe`? Вы запускаете на клиентской машине `vshost.exe`?

Comment: AVAST не стоит ли?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего на данном ПК не хватает библиотек .Net, которые вы используете. Может есть смысл сделать вывод в лог работы программы? Раз она запускается, то падает где-то в процссе работы.